# Sum formula in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, sum, ifs

In need assistance in creating a formula in google sheet that would give the sum of multiple cells which has ifs statement on it.

Here's the google sheet file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TgeCfni7fqvSUt1dTq4nwOX37p50OrfszWDZgW62hw0/edit?usp=sharing

Just need some help on how to fix it. Thanks!

One more thing, if you can look at it. In G2 formula? It should be 2 since B2 is equal to or greater than 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed formula from

`=IFS(A2>$E$3, "2",A2<$E$2, "0", A2>$E$2, "1")`

to

```
=IFS(A2>$E$3, 2,A2<$E$2,0, A2>$E$2,1)
```